# Elementor Sub-menu not showing in custom templates

Tags: wordpress, elementor, submenu

I create header of my website in elementor and there is also some custom templates in which elementor header sub-menu is not showing.

Firstly i think its my browser cache issue but after clearing cache of my browser issue is still there.

Comment: More information would be helpful, and maybe some example code for templates that work and those that don't.

Comment: May be you need to edit display condition for specific header.

Comment: I am not good at code can I share website link so you can check